# How is Thanatos typically built?

Tags: smite

So, I've just unlocked Thanatos and ended up playing him twice in Assault. However, I was building him as I would a typical basic attacking god with extremely poor results. I'm fairly sure that's the wrong way to go about it.

I realize builds can adjust depending on match-up. So, assuming a fairly generic match-up where you can build Thanatos in an optimal way to maximize his strengths, what is a typical Thanatos build?

Answers don't necessarily need to include specific items, unless items are typically included as a core-nearly-required selection. At the very least, guidance on which stats/effects to focus on and in what quantities is sufficient.

Comment: usually the game's recommended items are a great base build. Tweak it as you need for matchups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanatos is a typical jungle god. Build physical damage and penetration. My build is Bumba's Mask, Warrior Tabi, Jotunn's Wrath, Titan's Bane, Brawlers Beat Stick. Then late game, sell Bumba's Mask and Buy Deathbringer. If you want, build Bloodforge instead of Brawlers Beatstick for the lifesteal while sustaining high damage, however I find his 1 ability has enough lifesteal.

Answer (score 2):

So I play joust mostly, but I find that if you're playing thanny in a lane game, it works best for me when I finish his cooldowns as fast as possible, then focus on items that keep him in the fight. Since he cuts down other players pretty quick, I feel it's important to keep him in the team fight and ramp to finish the kills.
I've gotten a lot of Deicides with thanny using this build.
First I build watchers gift, which extremely helps him stay in lane. thanatos's abilities already don't cost him much mana because they balanced that with his requirement of health in addition in his castings. I have used watchers gift always and it works like a charm.
In this order, I build warrior tabi, jotunn's wrath, mail of renewal, spirit robe, bloodforge, and that last item really doesn't matter at this point because if you have a good team, and you're playing him the right way you should have made them quit already haha..
With this build, focus on staying safe, and poking the enemy team with your skill shot (rank this up fast).

Answer (score 0):

Early game will be: Lifesteal = Attackspeed > Crit
it later shifts to: Crit > Attackspeed > Lifesteal

Go straight for boots since you don't need the jungle item with him, you have enough sustain.
Get and Asi after your Boots and then build into a Bloodforge and Executioner.
After that Rage and Deathbringer, consider selling your Asi for Wrath if you want more burst.

This is a build I have been using since it has enough burst and then followup to be viable in long teamfights and FG or GF kills.

Answer (score -1):

My custom item build is set up if so i want to start off with Messengers Mask, or Warrior Tabi.
(From top to bottom in order 1-6.)

1) Warriors Tabi.            If you want MessengerMask
2) Hastened Kagan.      Sell Hastened Katana for 
3)Shifters Shield.           MesengersMask. Youwill have more         4)Jotunns Wrath            Movement &Cooldown%. 
5)Transcendence
6)Bloodforge.                     BUT Negative Phys.Power&
                                   BasicAttack damage if swapped or sold 
 (MessengerMask can only replace Hastened Katana in this build) Otherwise its unbalanced